# Code to extrude 2d geometry to 3d

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

is there any simple way to extrude a 2d geomtry (vectors ) to a 3d shape

assuming extruding parameter are lenght (double) and angle (degree)

so it should render like a cone ( all z lines going to one point )

Comment: It's not clear: you want to render a 3D object in 2D, based on a 2D shape and the two extrusion parameters (or am I wrong)?

Comment: I think he wants to extrude from a 2D drawing with a single point of convergence (one-point perspective).

Comment: yes , egrunin is right.

I don't care about initial scale of the 2d drawing, i want a polygon with a single point of convergence which lenght and angle will be parametrized

Comment: What do you mean 'angle'? Angles to a single point will not be uniform for all points on a 2D polygon. Are you working with convex or concave polygons? The convex case would be quite trivial.

Answer (score 1):

(I'd make this a comment, but it's too big)

This isn't just an extruding problem

If it were, your original 2D image would produce either a cylinder with a series of holes in it (not really that useful unless you have a very sophisticated renderer doing either volumetrics or supporting transparency, and the polysort in that case would be very ugly) or 4 cylinders (if I extrude along the inner holes)

most extrusion algorithms don't deal with targeting a single point - that's more than extrusion, it's some form of raycasting

This looks suspiciously like a lighting issue - are you trying to do volumetric lighting, maybe show an effect where the light cone is and deal with the effect of a baffle in front of the light ?  Or are you trying to compute the geometry that would define the shadow cast by the object in front of the light ?